# jQuery Validate: Group Validation But Not Field Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, plugins

I'm using jquery validate and I've set up groups.  However, I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to validate each group seperately from the individual fields that it contains.

To illustrate this:

I have city, state, and zip ( in that order ).  If someone enters a value for zip, they should get positive confirmation ( I've got that part working with a green checkmark by the input ), however, so long as either state and zip are empty the group validation message should still show.

On various attempts I've come up to the following problems:
- User skips over "city" and the validation the message displays but then when input is provided for "zip", the validation message goes away. ( this is weird...maybe a bug? )
- User enters "city" and they get the group error message before they even get to enter "state"
- User enters "city" but won't get the checkmark because the other inputs in the group are empty

I'm leaning towards addressing this by overwriting the "onfocusout" event ( by having it check all the inputs in the group on focusout ) but not sure if there is a better way via some of validate's built in methods

Thanks!

*UPDATE

The solutions I've come up with are rather ugly and none of them work consistently, below is an example, it results in the inverse of the first problem I listed above.  Now the validation message only shows when the last field in a group is filled in.

Maybe group validation rely's on the validation result of the last test in a group?

Anyway...here's the mess I've come up with so far:

Set the group:

```
groups : { location : 'city state zip' }
```

Create a rule for the group ( note it has to be an array to preserve the order ):

```
rules : { location : ['city, 'state', 'zip']}
```

Now override the onfocusout:

```
    onfocusout : function(el) {
        var groups = this.groups
            , elName = el.name
            , elGroup = groups[elName]
            , $el = $(el)

        if (!this.checkable(el) ){
            this.element(el));
        }

        // If the element belongs to a group, validate all elements in the group 
        // that come before the current element
        if (elGroup) {
            var groupMembers = this.settings.rules[elGroup];

            for (var i=0; i<groupMembers.length; i++) {
                if ( groupMembers[i] === elName ) {
                    break;
                }
                this.element( $('[name="' + groupMembers[i] + '"]') );
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the "groups" feature of this plugin has a few issues that are still outstanding, a few of which look to be related to your problem.

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/search?q=groups

Comment: Yeah...I think you're right but I'm gonna hold out a bit longer in case someone has a reasonable immediate solution.  Knowing what I know now about jquery validate's support for groups I would have taken a much different approach :/

Comment: Why not just take groups out?  Just add your own logic to check for permutations of the grouped items.  It sounds like you're already somewhat doing that anyways with your green checkmarks.

Comment: Groups will have to stay in as a stopgap for now...eventually, however, if no other solution comes up, I'm gonna have to do as you suggest and come back to this and implement all the group/messaging stuff on my own...that would prob be the best solution but it's also  gonna be pretty time consuming

Answer (score 0):

you can use groups for that, take this example:

```
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        City: { required: true },
        Zip: { required: true },
        State: { required: true }
    },
    groups: {
        Location: "City Zip State"
    },
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
       if (element.attr("name") == "City" || element.attr("name") == "Zip" || element.attr("name") == "State") 
        error.insertAfter("#State");
       else 
        error.insertAfter(element);
   }
});
```

- the rules set the 3 fields to true
- the groups defines them to be validated as a group
- and the errorPlacement function defines where to put the error message

Comment: hmmm...while that should work, when I try that it, it fails to give the validation message so long as the last member of the group passes the test...?  For example:  the error message shows when I tab out of city, but it then goes away when I put text into the zip field

Comment: hm odd, ok let me see if i can revise that